# AngularJS Array ng-repeat issue

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a json data returns from php like this:

```
[
{
    "id": 143,
    "sender": "btknctTR",
    "title": "Batıkan Bu nedir bu bu ne bu",
    "date": "Jun 11, 2016 6:47:21 AM",
    "lastupdatedate": "Jun 11, 2016 1:48:54 PM",
    "category": "Sorular",
    "priority": "Kritik",
    "appointedRole": "Moderatör",
    "archived": true,
    "messages": [
        {
            "sender": "btknctTR",
            "message": "Test message",
            "date": "Jun 11, 2016 1:48:30 PM"
        },
        {
            "sender": "btknctTR",
            "message": "This i second test message",
            "date": "Jun 11, 2016 1:48:54 PM"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 198,
    "sender": "btknctTR",
    "title": "Yeni yeni yeniden",
    "date": "Jun 11, 2016 12:53:32 PM",
    "lastupdatedate": "Jun 11, 2016 8:18:39 PM",
    "category": "Diger",
    "priority": "Normal",
    "appointedRole": "Moderatör",
    "archived": true,
    "messages": [
        {
            "sender": "btknctTR",
            "message": "Yeni yeni yenidenYeni yeni yenidenYeni yeni yenidenYeni yeni yenidenYeni yeni yenidenYeni yeni yenidenYeni yeni yenidenYeni yeni yenidenYeni yeni yenidenYeni yeni yeniden",
            "date": "Jun 11, 2016 7:54:41 PM"
        },
        {
            "sender": "DonduranAtes",
            "message": "asdasd\r\n",
            "date": "Jun 11, 2016 7:54:50 PM"
        },
        {
            "sender": "btknctTR",
            "message": "sadasdasdasd",
            "date": "Jun 11, 2016 7:55:14 PM"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 3810,
    "sender": "btkncttr",
    "title": "asdasdasdasdas",
    "date": "Aug 6, 2016 10:55:36 AM",
    "lastupdatedate": "Aug 7, 2016 10:33:19 PM",
    "category": "Diger",
    "priority": "Normal",
    "appointedRole": "Moderatör",
    "archived": true,
    "messages": [
        {
            "sender": "btkncttr",
            "message": "This is the message",
            "date": "Aug 6, 2016 10:57:07 AM"
        },
        {
            "sender": "player",
            "message": "This is the message tooo",
            "date": "Aug 6, 2016 10:57:07 AM"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

But I can't find how can ng-repeat theese. When I wrote **{{data.sender}}** *returns error [ngRepeat:dupes] in console*.

I need **list this values in ticket-list page**, this is a support system for *users*.

Comment: ng-repeat="item in data | track by $index" - try TRACK BY )

Comment: Please show all relevant code

Comment: ng-repeat="data in datas" track by $index

Comment: don't post *"Solution"* in the question..you accept an answer to point to what worked best for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `[ngRepeat:dupes]` error in console because there are some duplicates in the data.

If you want to loop through all the data and show `sender`, You can do something like this

```
<div ng-repeat="data in jsonData track by $index">{{data.sender}}</div>
```

`$index` keeps track of each object in the array using index of the object in the array.

Comment: This is the completely true answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your object is in the value of the variable $scope.data.

Then you can render this in your html with angular as following:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data track by $index">
    {{ item.id }}
</div>
```

Update: Indeed, with this specific error you need track by $index

Comment: `<tr ng-repeat="data in datas">
      <td >{{data.id}}</td>
  </tr>`

I'm already trying with it.
Error `angular.js:13920 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=dataa%20in%20datas&p1=object%3Anull&p2=null`

Comment: `ng-repeat="data in datas" track by $index`

Comment: @Akis it is true with this type 


`ng-repeat="data in datas track by $index"`


Thank you for answers, thanks for solution @Akis

Comment: @BatıkanGençACAT made it an answer with explanation, gona update it more

Answer (score 0):

Try this, 
[Here is working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devidas7/Lvc0u55v/10351/). 
Also check the Angular version, It should minimum 1.2, since it was introduced in that version.

```
 <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="data in datas track by $index">
    Sender : {{data.sender}}
    <br> Messages :<br>
    <div ng-repeat="(mindex, mvalue) in data.messages">
       {{mindex+1}}. {{mvalue.message}} - {{mvalue.date}}
    </div>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```